# How to manage data from same microservice on different AWS infrastructure

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, rest

Currently we have a micro-service (Java based) deployed to fetch, modify and save data on AWS infrastructure, which consists of a data lake.

Our AWS based data lake consists of S3, Kinesis, Athena, RDS, Airbyte connectors, Airflow, etc. We have designed our AWS data lake to store, process and manage data of 100 different clients, which are identified by app_id.

If the number of applications increase more than 100, we create a new AWS infrastructure with same resources for data lake and Java based micro-service.

We have created a client UI which interacts with micro-service to see final statistics of data stored in data lake after it is processed.

Now the problem is that UI is deployed on a separate infrastructure. If admin users wants to view data from 1 to 100 app_ids, it should call micro-service deployed on host1. If the data is needed from 101 to 200, host2 micro-service should be called.

How can I achieve this? Based on app_id, the server should redirect the REST call to correct host.

One way that I think of is that each host should maintain the in-memory map of all the hosts and their app_ids. This in-memory map will be maintained on each host. We will create a separate endpoint for UI which it can query and pass app_id. Based on app_id, the micro-service (backend) will return a hostname and then UI will call the actual API
deployed on that host name.  The code for the same is as follows:

```
@Override
    public HostApplicationMappingsResponseDTO getHostForApplicationByIdAndName(String applicationId, String applicationName,
           boolean isRefreshRequired, String token, String origin) throws IOException {
        LOGGER.info(" Entering in getHostForApplicationByIdAndName {}", applicationId);
        ApplicationDTO applicationDTO = clusterCloudRepository.getHostForApplicationByIdAndName(applicationId, isRefreshRequired, token, origin);
        if (applicationDTO == null) {
            return new HostApplicationMappingsResponseDTO(new com.firm.controller.dto.Error(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value(),
                    HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.getReasonPhrase(), "Application not found", null));
        }
        return applicationDTO;
    }

    @Override
    public FirmApplicationListResponse getApplicationByHost(String token, String origin) throws IOException {
        LOGGER.info(" Entering in getApplicationByHost {}");
        FirmApplicationListResponse response = new FirmApplicationListResponse();
        List<ApplicationDTO> appList = clusterCloudRepository.getApplicationsByHost("", token, origin);
        if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(appList)) {
            return new FirmApplicationListResponse(new com.firm.controller.dto.Error(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value(),
                    HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.getReasonPhrase(), "Applications not found", null));
        }
        response.setApplications(appList);
        return response;
    }
```

This approach results in 2 REST calls. Is there any way to achieve in a single call?

Answer (score 0):

I see two ways to solve this although one of them is effectively still two round trips.  The simplest way would be to simply do a redirect.  Note that the code below is standard JAX-RS but Spring has the exact same concepts:

```
@Path("/")
public class Redirector {

    @GET
    @Path("/getData/{applicationId}")
    public Response getData(@PathParam("applicationId") String applicationId,
                            @HeaderParam("Authorization") String token ) throws URISyntaxException {

        // validate token - likely should have been something before this

        // determine host based on application id
        String hostName = getHostFromApplicationId( applicationId );

        return Response.seeOther(new URI("https://" + hostName + "/some/other/parameters")).build();
    }

    private String getHostFromApplicationId(String applicationId ) {
        if( Integer.parseInt(applicationId) < 100 )
            return("host1");
        else
            return("host2");
    }
}
```

It's not 100% clear from your post what the other parameters are in the call but this is the concept at least.  What will happen is that the UI will do an HTTP GET of the data and code like this will redirect (303 HTTP response code) to the appropriate host.  Obviously the host choice needs to be more complex but this is the concept.  Note that if the UI is a browser the redirect is transparent to you - browsers should follow it automatically.

The alternative is to build a proxy for the data that automatically routes to the correct place transparently.  The proxy will do the reading of the data and pass it back to the UI.  This is a bit more complex but prevents the two calls.

Redirects are extremely common in a web environment and, while there are two round trips, your code shouldn't care as long as it can follow the redirect.